# Multiple varchar rows in PIVOT Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table values:

[image]

I want to do the pivot thing with this table. The result should be in format of,

**sample output:**

```
| Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor|

Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane

Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia

NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

I tried the following,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name,occupation
    FROM Occupations
) s
PIVOT
(
    max(name)
    FOR occupation IN (Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor)
)pvt
```

But,it returns only one row. Because of **MAX**

How can I achieve this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ROW_NUMBER` column:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name)
        FROM  #Occupations) AS s
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(name)
    FOR occupation IN (Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor)
  )pvt
)
SELECT Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor
FROM cte;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406833)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  Doctor  ║ Professor ║ Singer ║ Actor ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ Jenny    ║ Ashley    ║ Meera  ║ Jane  ║
║ Samantha ║ Christeen ║ Priya  ║ Julia ║
║          ║ Ketty     ║        ║ Maria ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```